Retrieving user and group name of a file and storing it in different variables in Linux using Ansible
How to retrieve the user and group name associated with a file in Linux using Ansible, i repeat not id's but names. Or if there is any shell command that i can use in Ansible. I checked even in the stat module documentation but couldn't find anything related to the names, only numeric id retrieval part was present.I need the string name of user and group to use it afterwards.

if there is any shell command that i can use in Ansible. : I have never worked in Ansible, but from my understanding, you can execute external programs from it. See here.

@user1934428 indeed it's possible but in Ansible whenever you can achieve the goal with the existing modules or their combination their usage is preferred over using shell commands.

Pure Linux commands. username: stat -c '%U' file.txt group: stat -c '%G' file.txt username: ls -l file.txt | cut -f3 -d " " group: ls -l file.txt | cut -f4 -d " ". All easily found solutions searching StackOverFlow and using your favored Internet search engine. But as mentioned, always use ansible modules when their is an ansible solution.

You must have missed this in the documentation for the stat module. ansible.builtin.stat:gr_name ansible.builtin.stat:pw_name


I checked even in the stat module documentation but couldn't find anything related to the names

From the stat module documentation:

gr_name - Group name of owner


pw_name - User name of owner

- name: Get stats of a file
  ansible.builtin.stat:
    path: /etc/foo.conf
  register: st

- name: Show the username
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: st.stat.pw_name

- name: Show the group name
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: st.stat.gr_name

